# How can I remove text from an image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fill, background-removal

I have the following image with written text over it. The image is a flat .jpeg, so I don't have access to the layers:

[image: http://f.cl.ly/items/14361k2o1V1Y2G051Z03/spaceFull.jpg]
<sup>Click image for full resolution</sup>

As you can see, the written text ("SPACE") is quite big.

**My question is: are there any effects/anything I can do in order to remove the text and still keep the background? Or at least hide it a little bit more?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Of course!

[`Content-aware fill`](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/content-aware-fill-cs5/) is your best friend in this case.

Just make a selection around the word and go `Edit -> Fill -> Content-Aware`.

This usually does a pretty good job:

[image]

<sup>Click image for full resolution</sup>

Then you can either go back over it multiple times (maybe in smaller sections) with Content-Aware fill to clean it up, or you can play with the [`Spot Healing Brush Tool`](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/retouching-repairing-images.html#main-pars_heading_7) (<kbd>J</kbd>) or the [`Clone Stamp Tool`](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/retouching-repairing-images.html#main-pars_heading_1) (<kbd>s</kbd>).

Comment: Wow, that really works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

#### Heal selection with Gimp

For people who work with Gimp there is the plugin [Resynthesize](https://github.com/bootchk/resynthesizer) together with the Python script [Heal Selection](https://github.com/bootchk/resynthesizer). On Linux the plugin comes with the package **gimp-plugin-registry**.

1. Select an area to remove from the image.
2. Choose *Filters - Enhance - Heal Selection*.

   [image]
3. Adjust the pixel width (here *300*), region (here *all around*), and fill pattern (here *random*) to resynthesize the selected area from it's surrounding.

The processing takes some time but the plugin does it's job extremely well. Depending on the background structure (and our settings of course) we may not even need any postprocessing:

[image]

I mostly use this tool to remove unwanted items or people from photos.

[image]
<sup>Source</sup>
[image]
<sup>4 items removed</sup>

Comment: +1 For the good answer and the Bonus game of *What's different about these pictures?*.

Comment: +1 even thought the question was tagged photoshop... this is a great example of where opensource freeware can outperform expensive adobe products.

Comment: I always use Resynthesize to remove unwanted objects. it works perfect with various kind of selections. You can trust gimp for these kind of operations. @amaster507 Gimp is not a freeware it is a freesoftware. There is a lot difference in freeware and free software.

Answer (score 4):

Simple...

Here I made a **Clipping Path** first. Then Photoshop will work magic through **Content-Aware Fill**.

Check the tutorial; you are going to learn how do I remove it.

[image]

[image]