# How do I extend an image by adding blur to sides?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, images, blur

I need to make an image 1080 x 1920. But when I do, the image looks very distorted. Is there a way I can extend an image by adding this blur to the sides of it? Also, does anyone know what this is called? I use Gimp as my primary editor. Any feedback would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: This image isn't extended. This is simply taking the original image, leaving it as it is .. then duplicating  it, expanding it to cover the whole background, setting it to be behind the original image and then applying a gaussian blur to it.

Comment: To me, for the background, it looks like they doubled the size, split it in half, and spread the halves to create a "vertical letterbox"

Comment: I'd also like to know the technical term for this ubiquitous technique. And secondarily how to stop everyone from doing it to any picture or video, ever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are steps with Gimp (or any other image processing software) to add a blurred border to an image.

[image]

1. Select all of the image (*Select > All*)
2. Shrink selection to desired size for paste below (7).
3. Feather selection to desired size for paste below (7).
4. Copy selection (*Edit > Copy*) to clipboard
5. Scale image to desired output size.
6. Blur the scaled image (here I just used a radial blur):

[image]

7. Paste the image from clipboard:

[image]

---

From the set of G'MIC plugins we also have a preset filter for a simple blurred frame (*Frames > Frame [blur]*).

[image]

---

In case the background of an image we want to extend is not blurred but has many details we can use the [Heal Selection](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/20893/12941) tool to fill the extended areas.

1. Crop-Extend source image to desired size:

[image]

2. Select the extended background to apply heal selection:

[image]

3. Add blur to hide the artifacts produced by heal selection:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Someone created a tutorial on youtube on how to do it in Davinci Resolve (free), fairly straightforward. https://youtu.be/Z8-gNkDT3HU