# Batch convert portrait photo to landscape with blurred, extended background - Windows utility needed (NOT Photoshop)

Tags: background, batch-processing, blur, scale

For a slideshow I want to extend 82 portrait images to landscape so that the image is duplicated as a blurred background, like this:

[image]

will be turned into

[image]

This is a one-shot-thing that I probably won't need again soon, so I'd need to use some free (or time limited trial) Windows utility for that. (I know that there are ways using Photoshop scripting, but I don't have Photoshop. I do have Corel PhotoPaint, if that's of any use.)

Do you know of any quick and dirty way to achieve this?

Comment: You can download a trial of Photoshop, is there any other reason you don't want to use it?

Comment: GIMP ( https://www.gimp.org/downloads/ ) blur cut move

Comment: @CAI - hhhmmm.... good point. I've always been a bit scared of PS's complexity and steep learning curve. To create trial account, download, install, figure out how it works and do the job would need to be faster than doing the 82 pics manually in Photodraw... ;-)

Comment: @Yorik - could you explain that in a bit more detail, please? Especially what steps I'd need to follow to achive that in batch-mode for all pics at once?

Comment: I have never done it, nor have I used GIMP. GIMP does support scripting and batching AFAIK. The obvious way is: open; duplicate layer 2x; double canvas width (w) with origin on center; move bottom layer -1*(w/2) pixels; blur bottom layer; move middle layer 1*(w/2) pixels; blur; save-as; revert; close-no-save. Note that "canvas width" is different than image width in that it will add pixels to image definition without resizing. The trick is working out (rehearsing) the steps and then working out how to record them.

Comment: Image Magik could certainly do that; look at the blur tool http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/ and the composite tool http://www.imagemagick.org/script/composite.php and finally the http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/

Comment: Example for Gimp: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63972/how-do-i-extend-an-image-by-adding-blur-to-sides

Comment: Well, Not many people use it, but Photopaint is in fact quite more powerful than Gimp, and you can also do it very easy. The concept is exactly the same as Photoshop. The macro window is Ctrl+F3. https://support.corel.com/hc/en-us/articles/215825848-Automating-tasks-and-batch-processing-images-in-Corel-PHOTO-PAINT

Answer (score 4):

@Metasomatism: Your comment lead me to the solution. If you change that to an answer I'll gladly accept it.

The command that does the trick is

```
for /f "delims=?" %f in ('dir *.jpg /b') do convert -size 1024x768 xc:skyblue "%f" -blur 0x25 -geometry 1024x768 -gravity northwest -composite "%f" -geometry 1024x768 -blur 0x25 -gravity southeast -composite "%f" -geometry 1024x768 -gravity center -composite "new_%f"
```

The commandline for ImageMagick is essentially this:

```
convert -size 1024x768 xc:skyblue 
        in.jpg -geometry 1024x768 -blur 0x25 -gravity northwest -composite
        in.jpg -geometry 1024x768 -blur 0x25 -gravity southeast -composite
        in.jpg -geometry 1024x768 -gravity center -composite
        out.jpg
```

which first creates an empy (well, light blue) canvas of the desired size (here 1024x768 as the images will be shown on an XGA beamer). Then the picture *in.jpg* is added three times: once in the topleft corner being heavily blurred, once more in the lower right hand corner, also blurred, and once in the center, this one unblurred. This yields the desired effect. It also handles panorama pictures, i.e. pics that are in wide landscape mode. Here, the blurred image is added to the top and bottom, whereas normal portrait pics the blurred pics are to the left and right.

Comment: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"delims=?"'

Am I missing something?

Comment: @Forkrul Assail: That is a Windows batch-loop, not linux