# How to remove faces in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, photo-editing

I see other people do this, to make it look like a person has no facial features at all, akin to Slenderman.

I'd like to do this on my own, but Google heeds no results.

I know it has something to do with the clone tool, but it can't be simple as that as I tried using the clone tool and this is the best I was able to do:

[image: My best attempt using the clone tool]

I could use the smudge tool, but that makes the faces look blurry and not very realistic at all.

Comment: I'd do that with the [Heal Selection](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/20893/12941) tool.

Comment: Realistic? How a man without a face look realistic? What is the type of image you need? https://www.google.com/search?q=El+laberinto+del+fauno ? https://www.google.com/search?q=Rorschach+Watchmen ? https://www.google.com/search?q=invisible+man ?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest / most convenient / cleanest way I can think of is a lasso cutout + clone stamp.

I would cutout all the *facial features* in a Y shape. Be precise and you'll see what I mean. After that I'd take the Clone Stamp and define a source point where the skin color is close to the area you want to remove the facial feature of. Fill the area with the texture, redefine your texture source for the Clone Stamp where needed.

For example, a good source point for filling the now empty space for the nose and mouth would be the cheeks. But as for the eyebrows and eyes, the forehead might be a better choice for the color and texture.

The devil is in the details, I would use smudge only in very rare and precise occasions.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly it looks like someone did that effect using a smudging tool. Gimp has a smudger though I don't know about Ps because I have never used it before.