# How can I replicate Photoshop's content-aware fill in Gimp for Windows?

Tags: gimp, software-recommendation, fill, windows

I want to remove an object from a photograph based on the surrounding patterns. In photoshop I could use the Content Aware Fill Tool, but there doesn't seem to be any built-in alternatives for Gimp on Windows.

Every guide I've found on this subject recommends the [Resynthesizer plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/25219), but the description says it is only available for Linux. (The plugin also doesn't seem to have been updated for a few years)

**Is there a tool similar to Photoshop's content aware fill tool I can use with GIMP for Windows?**

[image: Content aware fill]

Comment: That's a special feature in Photoshop that I haven't heard is offered in other programs. This seems like a purely software question so it's not really in the right place, although its purely graphic design software, so i don't know.

Comment: @webster AFAIK the resynthesize plugin appeared on Gimp before its PS equivalent.

Comment: Just a note to the OP - the GIMP Registry site is somewhat outdated and you seem to have found an older page, but the Windows version is available for download: http://registry.gimp.org/node/27986 - not the page you linked to.  This is the same link provided by @xenoid

Comment: See https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/20893/12941

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is a "resynthesize" plugin. It is available from the Gimp registry  (possibly [here](http://registry.gimp.org/node/27986)). But the best way to install it are:

- on Linux (at least for Ubuntu and derivatives), install package `gimp-plugin-registry` (it is included in a set of rather useful plugins).
- On Windows and OSX, the Gimp builds available on http://www.partha.com include it.

Patdavid has an [excellent tutorial on the subject](https://patdavid.net/2012/08/getting-around-in-gimp-heal-selection.html).

Comment: I can confirm the GIMP Registry link for Resynthesizer and the associated Python plugins including "Heal Selection" etc, definitely work in Windows.  And you are right - GIMP had these way before Photoshop.